# iOS increasing memory usage with two view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, memory

I have two ViewControllers.. the first one is a grid of UIButtons, and the second one is a detailed description based on the button they press.

I'm expecting that after they press a UIButton, and then press the back button in the navigation bar, the net change in memory should be zero.

Instead, I'm seeing an increase in memory, and I have no idea why. What happens when a user clicks the back button? How do I completely dismiss the detailed ViewController, completely releasing it from memory? Is there something specific I have to do?

ARC, xcode 4.2.1, iOS 5.0+

Thanks!

EDIT: I used the leaks tool, and there were no leaks discovered. In prepareForSegue, I pass an app object which is an NSDictionary to my new ViewController.

```
-(IBAction)toApp:(UIButton*)sender {   
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showApp" sender:sender];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton*)sender {
    AppViewController* vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.app = [self.apps objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
}
```

Comment: How and where are you creating the second UIViewController?  This question will be much easier to answer if you post some code.  Also, if you repeatedly go back and forth between the two view does your memory usage keep growing indefinitely or does it stop?

Comment: posted where I do my push segue. When i repeatedly go back and forth between the two views, my memory usage keeps growing indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a retain loop. Use the Allocations tool in Instruments with [Heapshot](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) to find it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm new to this, can I ask you a few follow ups? 
I noticed that of the 1-2 mb increase, CFData makes up most of it. What is CFData? What should I do now that I know this?

Comment: CFData is another name for NSData. Open the "Extended Detail" pane (Cmd-E). Double-click on the CFData entry to see the instances. Select an instance that is still alive (it should have a little diamond). The extended detail pane will tell you where it was created. That should help you find the leak.

Comment: Thanks! 
my CFData is made up of a bunch of 1.5 kb instances, where the event type is Malloc and the Responsible Caller is HTTPProtocol::bytesAvailable(), and Responsible Library is CFNetwork. I'm not sure what to do next

Comment: You need to keep working your way up the stack to see what object these are part of. Remember: the tool isn't going to tell you where you leaked it (i.e. where your mistake is); it just tells you where the memory was created. If I had to guess, I'd guess you're creating a long-running NSURLConnection in your view controller, and abandoning it when you switch view controllers. This is a broken design. All network traffic should be managed in the model classes, never in the view controllers.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was doing a NSURLConnection in my ViewController, so I'll redesign my classes

Comment: Is that also true if you're loading UIImages off the internet? Should that also be done in a model class instead of the UIViewController?

Comment: Generally yes. The model should hold all of your data. The views display it. The view controllers coordinate between the two. The main thing to remember is that a view controller can come and go whenever the user taps a button. It shouldn't hold anything that is "important" since it can vanish at any time.